# BST is not abstract and does not override abstract method height() in TreeGT

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am receiving the error: **BST is not abstract and does not override abstract method height() in TreeGT**. I need some help with understanding what it means, and how I can get resolve it.

In the file TreeGT.java I have the following code:

```
public interface TreeGT<E> {
    public boolean insert(E item);
    public boolean delete(E item);
    public boolean find(E item);
    public int height();
}
```

In the file BST.java I have the following code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class BST<E extends Comparable<E>> implements TreeGT<E> {

private Node root; //Only root by itself
public BST() {
    root = null;
    }

private static class Node {
    Comparable data; 
    int height; //Height of node 
    int size; //Number of nodes in tree
    private Node left; //Left subtree   
    private Node right; //Right subtree 

    Node (Comparable data) { //Constructor for tree 
        this.data = data;
        this.height = 0; //Height zero
        this.size = 1; //Root counts
        this.left = null; //No left leafs
        this.right = null; //No right leafs
        }
    }

    public void makeEmpty() {
        root = null;
        }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return root == null;
        }       

    public int size() {
        if (isEmpty())
            throw new Exception("Tree is empty");
        return root == null ? 0 : root.size;
        }

public boolean insert(E item) { 
return false;
}

public boolean delete(E item) { 
return false;
}

public boolean find(E item) { 
return false;
}

}
```

P.S. I have only been programming in java a few days, so you will have to speak as simple/straight forward as possible, please. Also, I am trying to create a BST. I think I am on the right path, no?

Answer (score 4):

An interface is a collection of undefined (i.e. abstract) methods. When you implement an interface (which you do in `implements treeGT`) you have to provide a definition for ALL of those methods. So, since your class implements treeGT, and height() is one of the abstract methods defined in treeGT, you have to define that method in your class.

i.e. you need to add

```
public int height(){
    //do something
}
```